# Iterate everything except UIContainerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I have a custom class (that I get from SO) to iterate all and every single subclass of `UIView`. What I don't get is I cannot add code to exempt the `UIContainerView`.

The code (in UIView+Recursion.m):

```
- (NSMutableArray*)allSubViews
{
    NSMutableArray *arr= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:self];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        [arr addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)[subview allSubViews]];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

So I want to add in the for loop, if it is UIContainerView, then don't add to the array. What I tried:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)allSubViews
{
    NSMutableArray *arr= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:self];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if (![subview isKindOfClass:[UIContainerView class]]) <-- error use of undeclared identifier
        [arr addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)[subview allSubViews]];
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Complete error message:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'UIContainerView'

The category class seem to be not recognizing the `UIContainerView`?

Comment: What is `UIContainerView`? It's not a public class.

Comment: Please add the original error message in your Q. Which identifier is undeclared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you wish to check for a private class which is why your code won't compile. If this is what you really need to do, then you can use `NSClassFromString`:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)allSubViews
{
    Class cvclass = NSClassFromString(@"UIContainerView");
    NSMutableArray *arr= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:self];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if (![subview isKindOfClass:cvclass]) {
            [arr addObjectsFromArray:[subview allSubViews]];
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I wonder though why Apple make UIContainerView as private. And also I wonder if they will reject my app for using this?

Comment: It's private because it's for internal use only. And yes, there's a (small?) chance your app might be rejected. Only one way to know for sure.

Comment: I have a workaround - just use tag, but I dislike tags, it creates so much dependency. Anyway I'm going to use this (NSClassFromString) and hope Apple won't reject it. Let us pray to Steve Jobs.